# How to use ARMA GARCH to do forecasting in R?

Tags: programming

How to use ARMA GARCH to do forecasting in R? I only know how to use ARMA to do the prediction and GARCH to do volatility forecasting but how can we use ARMA GARCH to do forecasting in R. Can anyone solve the problem with R code. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(fGarch)

fit = garchFit(~ arma(2,1)+garch(1,1), data = y,include.mean=FALSE)
predict(fit, n.ahead = 10, plot=TRUE, crit_val=2)
```

see  [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/fGarch.pdf) (page 30) for more details